# RESTful routing in FuelPHP

Tags: restful-url, fuelphp

Hello I am having some difficulty setting up a RESTful routing for a login controller. I keep getting hit with a status 404. Here is what I have so far. Any ideas?

In my routes:

```
'login' => array(
    array('GET', new Route('session/login')), 
    array('POST', new Route('session/login'))
    ),
```

And in my sessions controller I have:

```
class Controller_Session  extends Controller_Template {
    public function get_login(){
        return View::forge('session/login');
    }
    public function post_login() {

        return View::forge('session/login',$data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Apache error. The mod rewrite module was not activated on a Debian Based OS

Answer (score 1):

Try it using the default routing and the Rest controller.

```
class Controller_Session extends Controller_Rest
{...}
```

Delete the routes you set up and try accessing the Controller using `{url}/session/login`

Answer (score 0):

basically delete all routes you have created.

Then create a controller session.php:

```
class Controller_Session  extends Controller_Rest
//class Controller_Session  extends Controller_Hybrid
{

    public function get_login()
    {
        return View::forge('session/login');
    }

    public function post_login()
    {

        return View::forge('session/login',$data);
    }

}
```

You can extend Controller_Hybrid, if you want to access to both rest and non-rest methods.

Now try with jquery to access url: '/session/login'

It should work!

Good luck